# How come dice coefficient comes in bigger than 1

Tags: matlab, validation, dice, coefficients

I want to evaluate my automatic image segmentation results. I use Dice coefficients by a function written in Matlab. Following is the link for the code.
[mathworklink](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29737-segmentation-evaluatation/content/sevaluate.m)

I am comparing the segmented patch and manually cropped patch; interestingly DICE comes in bigger than one. I dispatched the code many times such as taking the absolute value of patches(to get rid of negative pixels) but could not find the reason. How come, while sum each individual set  is (say 3 and 5), and their union comes (say 45)?  The maximum of union must be 8.

Can somebody guide me more precise sources to implement dice coefficients?

```
function[Dice]=evaldem(man,auto)
for i=1:size(auto,1)
for j=1:size(auto,2)
auto(i,j).autosegmentedpatch=imresize(auto(i,j).autosegmentedpatch,[224 224]);)
 man(i,j).mansegmentedpatch=imresize(man(i,j).mansegmentedpatch,[224 224]);
Dice(i,j)=sevaluate(man(i,j).mansegmentedpatch,auto(i,j).autosegmentedpatch)
end
```

Since I have many automatically segmented patches, and manually segmented patches, I stored them in structures[man and auto]. Structures` size is [i,j]. Definitely I have to imresize to have them be in equal size! Then, I call the FEX submission file. When it comes to negative pixels of these patches, they have some. Note that, I take the absolute value of these patches when I am computing 'common' and 'union' for Dice. All in all, I get still Dice values bigger than one.

Comment: Can you at least show us some of your code that calls that FEX submission?

Comment: As Suever mentioned - please supply your code so we'll know where could the problem be. It seems like there is a bug, becuase  by defintion, Dice coefficient should return values in the range [0,1]

Comment: It seems like handling negative pixel values of the patches that are to be compared. @Ibezito